# Matrix access by x/y coordinates without linear indexing and looping in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, matrix-indexing

I'm operating on very big, 2D, sparse matrices in Octave. I have hit the linear indexing limit of 2^31 and need to go bigger.

The problem is I have two same-sized vectors of X and Y coordinates and would like to modify respective points without a loop.

I have already tried looping over one dimension, and `arrayfun` - both work, but suffer from serious perfomance issues.

Is there any way to do this without recompiling Octave for 64bit linear indexing?

Example of what I would like to achive:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
x = [1 3]; y = [3 2];
B = getxy/setxy(A, x ,y) % [7 6]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are trying to do with your for loop?

Comment: Would it be possible to create a new sparse matrix with the X, Y coordinates and mask that onto the existing array?

Comment: Nevermind, just tried it and the assignment runs into the max index problem again.

Comment: @excaza I can't use linear indexing - because of the linear indexing limit

Comment: @TimAdams added an example

Comment: @er453r I didn't say [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511), I said [array indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html)

Comment: @excaza that is the purpose of the question, I don't know how to index this particular case :)

Comment: With the subscripts?

Comment: @excaza yes, I know it looks trivial but believe me it is not - give it a try

Comment: You said you used _sparse_ matrices, but in the example they're not. So do you use **sparse** or large **dense** matrices?

Comment: Are the x/y values previously set, or are they zero?

Comment: @AlexanderSolovets I use sparse matrices, the example is just to show what I want to achieve

Comment: @beaker x and y vectors are the arguments of the selection and are non-zero - see the example

Comment: Sorry, I mean to ask if the values at those subscripts in the original sparse matrix `A` were zero. If so we could possibly construct a new sparse matrix using the new `x,y,value` and add it to `A`.